# How to create visual profiler?

Tags: python, plot

I would like to visualize some statistics about a program's running time in `Python`. Unfortunately this program has written in `Fortran` and `C++`, and I cannot use any language specific visualization tool. From the output of the program I have created a class including the start time and the end time of different functions, and subroutines. For example:

```
class MyProgramRuntime:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo1CallTime
        self.foo1EndTime
        self.foo2CallTime
        self.foo2EndTime
```

I would like to get a similar plot like on the picture on the following link: [Picture](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/graphics/timeline-view.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if is this the best solution, but it works really nice for me. I have used the matplotlib.patches lib to plot as long rectangles as the actual function/subroutine runned in seconds. The variables in the class are float variables, I got them by extracting from the actual datetime the datetime of the program's beginning with datetime.timedelta.total_seconds() . The plotting looks like the following:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.patches as patches

    def plotRunningTimes(mpr): #mpr is an instance of the MyProgramRuntime class
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.subplot(111)
        ax.add_patch( patches.Rectangle( (mpr.foo1CallTime, 0.1),
                                          mpr.foo1EndTime-mpr.foo1Calltime,
                                          0.1) )
```